# How to hide party mode from search engines?

Tags: seo

How do I remove the party mode version of websites I build so that they do not show up in search engine results? So far party mode isn't indexing, but I am afraid the links could potentially become indexed and want to make sure I don't screw up my client's SEO.

For example:

```
www.example.com/?partymode 
#above should not be indexed
www.example.com/
#above *should* be indexed
```

Does party mode get indexed separately or does google automatically know exclude it?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the active parameters > no URL section https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6080550?hl=en#active_parameters. This will allow you to forbid the crawling of a webpage containing a specific query parameter.